# How to keep keep track of failed status?

Tags: python

I have the following class for the statuses:

```
class JobStatus(models.TextChoices):
    SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
    RUNNING = 'RUNNING'
    FAILED = 'FAILED'
    WAITING = 'WAITING'
```

Everytime I run a job, it will have one of those statues. The problem is when the job failed, there could be more than one reason for the fail. On one hand, I want somehow to know the reason. On the other hand, I don't want to add an Enum item for each status. I could keep another separated variable `fail_reason` that will contain the error, but it feels like bad design. I also thought of creating a field that will hold the reason and another field that will hold the status but not sure it's a good idea. What would be a good way to handle this issue?

PS: `models.TextChoices` is of Django (it's does not really matter what it does).

Comment: If you are only after capturing job logs, have you explored [Django's logging primer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/)?

Comment: @jwjhdev There other status that we keep (but all of them don't need a "reason"). It's a python question (not Django') about design classes.

Comment: @vesil okay not a problem, just wanted to make sure you weren't recreating the wheel.

Comment: @jwjhdev I see, thanks for your comment! :)

Answer (score 1):

I like using binary flags representing each status. Assign a value to each status:

```
class JobStatus(models.TextChoices):
    STATUS = {0: 'SUCCESS',
             2**0: 'RUNNING',
             2**1: 'FAILED',
             2**2: 'WAITING',
             2**N: 'LAST_STATUS'}
```

This keeps track of all possible status simultaneously and each combinations of statuses is unique, so you can keep track of all of them using the binary "AND" operation as shown below:

```
status = 3
if status == 0:
    status_text = STATUS.get(0)
else:
    for n in range(N):
        if status & 2**n == 2**n:
            status_text += STATUS.get(2**n)+", "
status_text = status_text[:-2]
```

That should return: "RUNNING, FAILED"
Obviously you can handle the strings anyway works for your project and just keep the integer status value in your code if you need to evaluate it in conditions.
I also like to use 0 as my 'SUCCESS' status, so anything greater than zero indicates a problem.